# How do I save a function that I want to frequently use?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, functions, view

Due to the nature of how I ingest data into my SQL database it's prone to duplicates so I have the following view:

```
SELECT IP, COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM ipdb
GROUP BY IP
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Current methodology is to then search for the offending duplicates and remove them one by one. It does require manual review because reasons, namely I have to determine the 'correct' or most up to date entry. Is there any way I can speed this up? Because lately what I've been doing is copying the offending IP into this query then deleting.

```
SELECT *
FROM ipdb
WHERE IP = '1.2.3.4'
AND IP IN (
    SELECT IP
    FROM ipdb
    GROUP BY IP
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
);
```

Comment: You have a column which is duplicated (IP). You have a column which sets the ordering (date). So you must simply remove the row if the row with the same IP value and greater date value exists.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Why not just create a View around the code you wrote?

Answer (score 0):

Plan A:  Start over, but this time have `PRIMARY KEY(IP)` and do `INSERT IGNORE`.  This will prevent dups from ever getting in.

Plan B:  Dedup, first:

```
  CREATE no_dups LIKE ipdb;
  ALTER TABLE no_dups ADD UNIQUE(IP);
  INSERT IGNORE INTO no_dups  SELECT * FROM ipdb;
  RENAME TABLE ipdb TO with_dups,
               no_dups TO ipdb;
  DROP TABLE with_dups;
```

Once you have a unique index on `ip`, use `INSERT IGNORE to prevent future dups.

If you also need to decide between the old row and the new, please explain the criteria.